# Follow-up After Asking For a Raise?

Tags: united-states, raise, school

Long story short, I have been with my current company for four years and have received a slight raise a year ago despite having more and more responsibility thrusted onto me. Additionally, because I am the only senior female engineer, I often get blamed for things that my (male) coworkers do that I am not privy to. (Think "boys will be boys" mindset while I have to babysit them and make sure they don't stick their fingers in the light socket else I will get berated.) Add the stress of our top senior engineer leaving, management has been taking their frustrations out on me, so it is not a fun time.

The company is owned by one of the top 10 engineer in our field and I have a very specialized but valuable skill set so I can go anywhere and have started to look for a new job. On top of it, they gave me way too much power and if I leave, they will have no one to run the backend (despite thorough documentation on my part which would ensure anyone could do it if they were inclined - they aren't.).

Two weeks ago, I got into the Master's program which will open up more opportunities to me. I was planning to do it exclusively online and take 3 years rather than two, but I am contemplating bull-rushing it in a year and leaving the company to do it.

Now with this in mind the actual question - since I am the next most senior engineer, I am going to ask for a raise, more PTO, and benefits (I have none while my other coworkers do). I know there is a very slight chance (1-2%) of getting the raise for the above reasons (re: I know they don't see me as a valuable team member) so I plan to take that Master's admission and take a year off for school while looking for a new job.

Because university starts August 23rd and I can sign up for classes until September 10th, if I send in my proposal for a raise today, how long should I wait for a follow-up?

I will need to follow-up as they are massive flakes.

Comment: We can't answer this question for you - you know your company far better than we do. That said, would you really want to stay even if you get some more money, PTO and benefits?

Answer (score 2):

> if I send in my proposal for a raise today, how long should I wait for
> a follow-up?

Wait a week before following up.

Don't expect much, but apparently you have nothing to lose.